# python-behave-invalid command when executing behave <feature file name>

Tags: python-behave

IDE PyCharm professional, python 3.4.5, behave 1.2.5, environment Windows 7; 
Note: I am running the command from the feature file directory;
When I attempt to execute a feature file using the behave  command syntax (ex: behave home_page.feature); the behave interpreter response with the following message 'invalid command name 'home_page.feature'. 
What might be causing behave interpreter to parse a feature file as a command name? Would this be an environmental issue? 
This was not an issue with the community edition 'Free' of PyCharm (I did upgrade to Professional to get full access to the Behavior Driven Development (BDD) features in the professional version of PyChram).

Answer (score -1):

FYI, behave has a `--help` argument to list available commands

You can't simply call `behave home_page.feature`
Doing so, behave (or any command line executable for that matter) thinks that `home_page.feature` is an argument itself

Instead behave uses the `-i` or `--include` arguments to search for feature files matching the provided regular expression
So instead, run behave like so `behave -i home_page`

Alternatively, you can add tags in your feature file with `@TAG_NAME`
You can then run those specific tags using `-t` or `--tags` arguments
Tags are helpful when you want to run a specific scenario of many scenarios in a feature

See https://pythonhosted.org/behave/behave.html for more information

Comment: It is absolutely possible to do `behave home_page.feature`.I invoke behave with feature files as argument *all the time*.